# Can I use VkDevice from multiple threads concurrently?

Tags: vulkan

In particular, can I create pipelines, allocate device memory and create images and buffers from the same VkDevice concurrently?

Where in the specs this is specified?

Comment: All Vulkan objects work under the same concurency rules. That being said, this is practically duplicate of [Are Vulkan renderpasses thread local in multi-threading rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51507986/are-vulkan-renderpasses-thread-local-in-multi-threading-rendering).

Comment: and [Can `vkCommandPool` be allocated from the main thread and the moved to other threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49275741/can-vkcommandpool-be-allocated-from-the-main-thread-and-the-moved-to-other-thr)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the specification we can read:

> Vulkan is intended to provide scalable performance when used on multiple host threads. All commands support being called concurrently from multiple threads, but certain parameters, or components of parameters are defined to be *externally synchronized*. This means that the caller **must** guarantee that no more than one thread is using such a parameter at a given time.

Then there is a list of parameters of different Vulkan functions in which they must be externally synchronized (meaning they cannot be accessed at the same time from multiple threads). In case of a `VkDevice` objects, we can find that only `vkDestroyDevice()`. So all other usages of a `VkDevice` objects can happen on multiple threads.

And there are practically no `vkCreate...()` functions in that list (only 3 swapchain related functions). Which means you can create objects from multiple threads at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Statements in the Vulkan specification of the form "host access to X must be externally synchronized" mean that you cannot cause accesses to X while also calling the function that has this requirement. If a function's specification *doesn't* say that about a particular parameter, then that parameter can be accessed from multiple threads. So long as all functions that could concurrently access it don't have this specification, of course.

Note that the Valid Usage section of various functions can have additional concurrency requirements.